# Fill in the region between two line curves in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I need to fill the region of two lines by '***hatched grey***' color. I used the following code:

```matlab
M = [0.54, 0.7, 0.74, 0.78];
X1 = [0.007856, 0.008394, 0.008607, 0.012584];      %X1 values
X2 =  [0.007901, 0.008461, 0.008739, 0.011302];      %X2 values
xq = (0.54:0.000001:0.8);   %adding intervals to make line smoother
X3 = interpn(M,X1,xq,'pchip');  %other type: pchip, makima, spline etc.
X4 = interpn(M,X2,xq,'pchip');  %other type: pchip, makima, spline etc.
set(0,'defaulttextinterpreter','latex')

figure(1)
hold all; 
plot(xq, X3,'r-','LineWidth',1.5);
plot(xq, X4,'b--','LineWidth',1.5);

X=[xq,fliplr(xq)];           %create continuous x value array for plotting
Y=[X3,fliplr(X4)];           %create y values for out and then back

fill(X,Y,'g');    %plot filled area
xlabel('X','FontSize',12); % Label the x axis
ylabel('Y','FontSize',12); % Label the y axis
axis([0.5 0.8 0.007 0.013]);
```

However, when I tried to make the line smoother the fill in command didn't take place! I need to keep the ***line smoother*** and fill the region with a '***hatched grey***' color at the same time.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please copy-paste your code into the question, a screen shot of code is not at all useful, can’t run that. Also make sure your code can run (contains example data), see [mre]. Finally, show what you did when you “tried to make the line smoother”.

Comment: Hello Cris, Thanks for pointing that out. I've added the MATLAB code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that `X3` and `X4` contain NaN values. This happens where you attempt to extrapolate, `interpn` adds NaN values there.

The array `xq` ends at 0.8, whereas the input data, `M`, ends at 0.78. You should make `xq` end at 0.78 as well. The best way to do this is as follows:

```
xq = M(1):0.000001:M(end);
```

Though do note that the interval is very small, which leads to way too many data points to plot, it is not necessary to have this many points for a smooth plot. I suggest you use `linspace` instead:

```
xq = linspace(M(1), M(end), 1000);
```

Here, the `1000` is the number of points.

Comment: Hi Cris, Thanks for the insight. It works well! Could you please tell me how can I change the fill-in color/shade from 'green' to 'hatched grey shade'?

Comment: @Rahman: I don't think MATLAB does hatched fills, and I certainly recommend that you don't use them. They were useful way back when computers could only draw with green on black, but that time has passed. But if you really must, then you'll have to download one of the utilities from the File Exchange. It seems this is the most popular one: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30733-hatchfill

Comment: Thanks @Cris for your time and help. I appreciate it.